# appropriate data structure for sorting a multi dimensional array in python?

Tags: python, data-structures

I have three numeric values (weight, count, contribution) for various strings (words) that i would like to organise into one multidimensional array, and then sort. To do this, I made lists within a dictionary, where the numeric values are in the list and the string is the key:

```
print_dictionary[word] = [weight,count,contribution]
```

How can I sort, first in ascending order and then in descending order, by 'contribution' (the third value in the list), and show the first 10 items of the sorted list. How can I do this?

For example, for the following print_dictionary:

```
print_dictionary[sam] = [2,7,1]
print_dictionary[sun] = [4,1,3]
print_dictionary[dog] = [1,3,2]
```

I want to them be able to sort contribution in ascending order:

```
Word:   Weight:   Count:    Contribution:
sam     2         7         1
dog     1         3         2
sun     4         1         3
```

I don't see how itemegetter can be used for this:

```
sorted(print_dictionary, key=itemgetter(2))
```

Comment: Lists _are_ ordered in python. I think you meant "dicts are unordered".

Comment: thanks, I edited the post to clear that up.

Comment: Also, you can't use itemgetter on a dictionary like that. You have to call `print_dictionary.items()`.

Comment: Do you just want the keys in order so that you can access it in contribution order?

Comment: I want to sort between sets, not within sets. I added an example in the question.

Comment: Right - so you want the keys in sorted order.  A dict is unordered and hence cannot be sorted, but its keys can be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an anonymous function as the key to `sorted`.  This uses the third member of the multi-dimensional dict as the key:

```
>>> d = {'a': [1, 4, 7], 'b': [2, 3, 9], 'c': [3, 2, 8]}
>>> for key in sorted(d, key=lambda x: d[x][2]):
...    print key, d[key]
a [1, 4, 7]
c [3, 2, 8]
b [2, 3, 9]
```

For descending order, use `reverse=True`.  To limit the results, add `[:N]`:

```
sorted(d, key=lambda x: d[x][2], reverse=True)[:2]

# b [2, 3, 9]
# c [3, 2, 8]
```

[More about `sorted` and sorting in Python](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting).

Comment: Close, just put the slice statement on sorted: `sorted(d, key=lambda x: d[x][2])[:10]`

Answer (score 1):

You can't really sort a dictionary; when you try, you are really just sorting the list of keys from the dictionary.  You can do that using a custom sort comparison that looks at the third item in the value.

```
sorted(print_dictionary, key=lambda word: print_dictionary[word][2])
```

So to generate your report, something like this would work:

```
sorted_keys = sorted(print_dictionary, key=lambda word: print_dictionary[word][2])

print "Word:\tWeight:\tCount:\tContribution"      
for i in range(10): # or however many you want
    word = sorted_keys[i]
    values = print_dictionary[word]
    print "\t".join([word]+[str(n) for n in values])
```