# Sort Multidimensional Dictionary by value and return newly sorted dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dictionary

below is the sample dictionary that I have.

```
    my_dict = {  
       '003':{  
          'class':'13',
          'marks':'90',
          'name':'CCC',
          'date_accessed':'2017-07-12 17:43:24'
       },
       '002':{  
          'marks':'90',
          'class':'10',
          'name':'BBB',
          'date_accessed':'2017-07-12 17:43:24'
       },
       '001':{  
          'marks':'80',
          'class':'9',
          'name':'AAA',
          'date_accessed':'2017-07-12 17:43:24'
       },
       '005':{  
          'date_accessed':'2017-07-12 17:43:42',
          'marks':'999',
          'name':'EEE',
          'class':'99'
       },
       '004':{  
          'class':'50',
          'marks':'100',
          'name':'DDD',
          'date_accessed':'2017-07-12 17:43:24'
       }
    }
```

Now I want to sort it by `marks`, so the resultant dictionary will be like this

```
    my_dict = { 
       '005':{  
          'date_accessed':'2017-07-12 17:43:42',
          'marks':'999',
          'name':'EEE',
          'class':'99'
       }, 
       '004':{  
          'class':'50',
          'marks':'100',
          'name':'DDD',
          'date_accessed':'2017-07-12 17:43:24'
       }
       '003':{  
          'class':'13',
          'marks':'90',
          'name':'CCC',
          'date_accessed':'2017-07-12 17:43:24'
       },
       '002':{  
          'marks':'90',
          'class':'10',
          'name':'BBB',
          'date_accessed':'2017-07-12 17:43:24'
       },
       '001':{  
          'marks':'80',
          'class':'9',
          'name':'AAA',
          'date_accessed':'2017-07-12 17:43:24'
       },
    }
```

Now, somehow I have achieve to sort it by `marks` using this equation

```
dict_sorted = sorted(my_dict, key=lambda x: int(my_dict[x]['marks']), reverse=True)
```

but this gives me only `keys` in a sorted manner, but I am not able to generate newly sorted dictionary like above. Kindly help me here to sort the dictionary by `marks` and gives new sorted dictionary. Thanks.

EDIT: I have already seen many posts here in stackoverflow like this [Sort a Python dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value) and this [Issue sorting a multi-dimensional dictionary that has non-numeric indices in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970704/issue-sorting-a-multi-dimensional-dictionary-that-has-non-numeric-indices-in-pyt) but these posts couldn't deliver the result that I required.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a Python dictionary by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)

Comment: Your goal dictionary is the same as the input dictionary (except for your typo).

Comment: Dictionaries are *unordered*. It makes no sense to say a "sorted dictionary." Your best option is to use an ordered mapping, like `collections.OrderedDict`. Why exactly do you need it "sorted" anyway?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Dictionaries are unordered** up to (and including) [python-3.5](/questions/tagged/python-3.5). Only for a few releases of [python-3.6](/questions/tagged/python-3.6) dictionaries are ordered. As is written in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation):

> The order-preserving aspect of this new implementation is considered
>   an implementation detail and **should not be relied upon** (this may
>   change in the future, but it is desired to have this new `dict`
>   implementation in the language for a few releases before changing the
>   language spec to mandate order-preserving semantics for all current
>   and future Python implementations; this also helps preserve
>   backwards-compatibility with older versions of the language where
>   random iteration order is still in effect, e.g. Python 3.5).

So we better be safe than sorry and **don't use a `dict`**.

In the `collections` there is an `OrderedDict` class that is a dictionary which maintains the order of the elements the way they were added.

We can thus now use it like:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict.items(),key=lambda x:int(x[1]['marks']),reverse=True))
```

Note that you have to use `.items()` to obtain tuples with a *key-value* pair. We then sort the elements by taking the value (the second element of the tuple) and from that value the value associated with the `'marks'` key.

In case you want **numerical comparison**, you should add an `int(..)` call, to convert them to integers first.

This generates:

```
>>> OrderedDict(sorted(my_dict.items(),key=lambda x:int(x[1]['marks']),reverse=True))
OrderedDict([('005', {'name': 'EEE', 'date_accessed': '2017-07-12 17:43:42', 'class': '99', 'marks': '999'}), ('004', {'name': 'DDD', 'date_accessed': '2017-07-12 17:43:24', 'class': '50', 'marks': '100'}), ('003', {'name': 'CCC', 'date_accessed': '2017-07-12 17:43:24', 'class': '13', 'marks': '90'}), ('002', {'name': 'BBB', 'date_accessed': '2017-07-12 17:43:24', 'class': '10', 'marks': '90'}), ('001', {'name': 'AAA', 'date_accessed': '2017-07-12 17:43:24', 'class': '9', 'marks': '80'})])
```

An `OrderedDict` is a **subclass of the *vanilla* dictionary** in Python. So all operations that are supported by `dict` are supported by `OrderedDict` as well.

Comment: Only CPython-3.6 implementation of dict are ordered, that feature will only   become an official python feature in a few releases , see [here](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#new-dict-implementation)

Comment: @jadsq: thanks for the comment. I added this to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well in python you can't really sort a dictionary as far as I know, I will use the following code:

```
def sort_dict_to_top_whatever(dict_to_sort, how_many_to_store):
    """
    function will sort the input dict and return the amount of the input number as top
    :param dict_to_sort: the dict with numbers at the values
    :param how_many_to_store: how much to take
    :return: the sorted dict
    """
    #                    -x: because we need to reverse sort:
    step1_sort_to_list = sorted(list(dict_to_sort.items()), key = lambda x: -int(x[1]["marks"]))
    step2_take_top = step1_sort_to_list[:how_many_to_store]
    step3_the_dict = {info[FIRST]: info[1] for info in step2_take_top}
    return step3_the_dict
```

and then:

```
sorted_dict = sort_dict_to_top_whatever(my_dict, len(my_dict))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the line you had to get the correct index order you want the dictionary in

```
dict_sorted = sorted(my_dict, key=lambda x: int(my_dict[x]['marks']), reverse=True)
```

Then loop through the dictionary using the new index order, and add to a new dictionary

```
newly_ordered = {}
for new_index in dict_sorted:
    # get the relevant item from the original dictionary
    item = file_list[new_index]
    print(item)
    # add to new dict
    newley_ordered = item
```